# Response webdesign: getting rightmost floating element

Tags: html, css, css-float, responsive-design

I want to design a webpage using responsive webdesign, such that the layout adapts to the screen size. I have some  elements with text that are beside each other if the screen width allows that. I use a float:left for this  elements. Now if the screen is small the articles show up below each other as expected.

Now my question is how to get the rightmost articles (appearing near the right edge of the screen), because they must have a right-border and the other articles not. Is this possible with css and html only?

Edit: I can replace the float:left with a display:inline, but then the question stays the same.

Comment: Do the elements have fixed widths? Otherwise, I don't think it can be done

Comment: The width is relative, but with a min-width and max-width